# SQL query pass column name dynamically

Tags: sql-server

This is my query I want to set column names dynamically, is it possible through query

```
select  
    branch,
    sum(case when months = 'JUL' then  [Parts Revenue Budget] end) as [JUL]
from 
    #final 
group by 
    branch
```

Something like this:

```
@Col as varchar(10);

select  
    branch,
    sum(case when months = 'JUL' then  [@Col] end) as [JUL]
from 
    #final 
group by 
    branch
```

I get this below error message

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Procedure CRM_FRN_PL_BR_MN, Line 215
>   Invalid column name @Col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @col varchar(10);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @col = 'some_field';
set @sql =  'select ' + @col + ' from #final';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Procedure 'CRM_FRN_PL_BR_MN' expects parameter '@sql', which was not supplied.

Comment: set @sql ='
select  branch,
       sum(case when months = ''JUL'' then  ['+ @a + '] end) as [JUL]
    from #final 
group by branch';

exec sp_executesql @sql;

Comment: It seems that the problem in the procedure with name CRM_FRN_PL_BR_MN.

Comment: no no that wasnt the problem I have figured it out thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called ***dynamic SQL***. It is supported by most DBMSs (you are not stating which one you are using though).

Normally, the process is to **PREPARE** a statement which is passed as a string, something like:

```
SER @Col_Name = 'Col_15' ;
SET @MySTTMNT = CONCAT('SELECT '           ,
                        @Col_Name     , ' ',
                       'FROM MyTable '     ,
                       'WHERE ID = '       ,
                       @MyVariable
                      ) ;
```

This string is then passed to a **Prepare** statement and then executed.

Check your DBMSs documentation for **Dynamic SQL**.